# Multiple Attribute Selector checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So I've got these labels with input checkboxes in it. Now after submit and the form is *not* accepted it returns *here* and I want it to *select* the previous selected box.

```
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="use your apple1">use your apple<span class="left" ></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="Zo maak je van onbekenden klanten1">Zo maak je van onbekenden klanten<span class="left" ></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="Multi media feest">Multi media feest<span class="left" ></span></label>

<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Pretwerk OPTIE!">Pretwerk OPTIE!<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="use your apple4">use your apple<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Snelheid is geld4">Snelheid is geld<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Fotograferen met je iPhone">Fotograferen met je iPhone<span class="left" "></span></label>
```

I've already used a hidden field etc. So I've got the returned value of the previously input.

```
var first = "<?php echo $first ?>";
//in this case I make first the value 'use your apple1'
$("[name$=group1][value=" + first + "]").prop("checked", "true");
```

So now it should check the box *use your apple* in *group1* 
But i get the error

`jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name$=group1][value=use your apple1]`

Comment: `name$`? should it be `name`?

Comment: `first` variable is an empty string, `[value=]` is causing the error..... and not `name$` it's valid... attribute ends with selector.. either provide quotes `$("[name$=group1][value='" + first + "']")`

Comment: no @guradio i tried using `name`, but it doesn't work. Looked online somewhere someone used `name$` and it worked for me

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid as you have some extra mis-matched double quotes in the `span` elements

Comment: @guradio, `name$` is valid attribute selector(_attribute starts with_)

Comment: @Rayon thanks noted :)

Comment: How do you mean @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Oh yea you're right @RoryMcCrossan didn't notice because didnt give me any errors just works properly. But thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Single quotes (')  `value=" + first + "]" to value='" + first + "']"`

```
var first = "<?php echo $first ?>";
//in this case I make first the value 'use your apple1'
$("[name$=group1][value='" + first + "']").prop("checked", "true");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var first = "use your apple1";
//in this case I make first the value 'use your apple1'
$("[name$=group1][value='" + first + "']").prop("checked", "true");
  
  //console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="use your apple1">use your apple<span class="left" ></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="Zo maak je van onbekenden klanten1">Zo maak je van onbekenden klanten<span class="left" ></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="Multi media feest">Multi media feest<span class="left" ></span></label>

<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Pretwerk OPTIE!">Pretwerk OPTIE!<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="use your apple4">use your apple<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Snelheid is geld4">Snelheid is geld<span class="left" "></span></label>
<label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="Fotograferen met je iPhone">Fotograferen met je iPhone<span class="left" "></span></label>
```

Comment: Thanks fixed it. I'll accept answer as soon as I can

Comment: You are suppose to provide reason.. May be _attribute value is having space_ is the reason!

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
$("[name$=group1][value=" + first + "]").prop("checked", "true");
```

to this

```
$("input[name=group1][value=" + first + "]").prop("checked", "true");
```

Comment: This is logically identical to what the OP already has. Why it was upvoted I have no idea.